# How do I edit a specific page so that it may be displayed in iframe?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, iframe

We have a separate intranet site that iframes a specific Sharepoint page.  It gives the following error: `To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.`

I've read that it's possible to allow iframing for specific pages.  How exactly do you modify a specific page in sharepoint 2013?  Can this be done without modifying the master page?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the page in SharePoint designer and the following tag

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

When building your iFrame use the `&IsDlg=1` or `&isdlg=1` query string parameter as well to hide the SharePoint Chrome.

Note

IsDlg = 1 (Hides chrome and wont' display scrollbars for content)

isdlg = 1 (shows scrollbars)

Comment: Should it be added in a specific place?